# Gnome shell extensions, preventing the call of `disable` when the screen gets locked

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

When the screen gets locked, my gnome shell extension is disabled. The shell calls `disable` function of the extension and `enable` is called again when the lock is released. Can I prevent this behavior? My extension needs to do something in background and it must not stop when screen is locked. I want `disable` is called only when the extension is disabled explicitly by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you could totally ignore `disable()` but your extension would be rejected on the extensions website (for obvious reasons). The only way to address this is to run some manner of daemon in the background, like the [Drop Down Terminal](https://github.com/zzrough/gs-extensions-drop-down-terminal) extension does.

The easiest way to do this is to write a simple [Gio.Application](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GApplication.html) and spawn it during `enable()` using `GLib.spawn_command_line_async`. See also: [HowDoI/GtkApplication](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/GtkApplication)

Answer (score 2):

Though this is an older thread I will leave my answer here, since I stumbled upon the same question.

Since Gnome 42 you can add the optional `session-modes` field to your `metadata.json`.
This prevents `disable` to be called on screen lock.

It has to contain `unlock-dialog`

```
  "session-modes" : [
    "user",
    "unlock-dialog"
  ]
```

This was particularly useful when subscribing and unsubscribing to a dbus signal in the `enable` and `disable` functions respectively.

See https://gjs.guide/extensions/overview/anatomy.html#optional-fields